# Initializing strongly typed dropdown list in asp.net from within a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three models for Province, District & Village. I also have a model for Employee.

the Employee Model:

```
public class Employee {
 public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
 public string FullName {get;set;}
 public int VillageId {get;set;}
}
```

the Province Model:

```
public class Province{
 public int ProvinceId {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

the District Model:

```
public class District{
 public int DistrictId{get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int ProvinceId {get;set;}

 public virtual Province province {get;set}
}
```

The Village Model:

```
public class Village{
 public int VillageId{get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int DistrictId {get;set;}

 public virtual District district {get;set}
}
```

Now i want my employee strongly typed view to have three drop down lists and when i select a province, then the district drop down list must be filled with those districts that are in the selected province and when i select a district the village drop down list must be populated with the villages that are in the selected district.

The village drop down should be of strongly type dropdown list.

Comment: Hey my friend. Just do your homework. First search in the web. There are many easy solution that you can find. Just search for asp.net mvc cascading drop down.

Comment: Of course i found lots of things but what I want is to be of strongly typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following examples show how to create cascading dropdownlists with strongly typed helpers.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258172/Simple-Implementation-of-MVC-Cascading-Ajax-Drop-D

http://www.dotnetpools.com/Article/ArticleDetiail/?articleId=169&title=MVC3-Cascading-DropdownList-Using-Jquery

http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Creating-a-Cascading-Dropdown-in-ASPnet-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx